# Get total count of aword in corpus using Countvectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I have corpus of the following format:

```
corpus = ['text_1', 'text_2', ... . 'text_4280']
```

In total there are 90141 unique words.
For each word, I want to calculate the total number of times it appears in `corpus`.

To do so, I used:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(corpus)
```

Currently, the only way I am aware of doing this is by:

```
vectorizer.fit_transform()
```

However, this will create a (sparse) Numpy array with shape `(4280, 90141)`. Does CountVectorizer has more memory-efficient approaches to get all the column sums of the document-term matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
vectorizer.fit_transform().toarray().sum(axis= 0)
```

> EDIT

my bad, you should just remove `.toarray()` from the above statement. I didn't realise that you could call `.sum()` on a sparse array

```
vectorizer.fit_transform().sum(axis= 0)
```

Comment: Doing this, I get a memory error as this approach requires 4.69 TiB of data

Comment: @Emil Remove the `.toarray()`. That's the part that's never, ever, ever going to happen. You can sum sparse arrays on columns without trying to turn them into 5 terabytes of zeros.